# R iGraph: is the first vertex always the central one in neighborhood?

Tags: r, igraph

I have noticed that, when calling the function [neighborhood](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/neighborhood), the first vertex in the list is always the central one (the vertex of interest). See for instance:

```
g <-graph_from_literal( a-b,a-c,d-a,a-e,a-f,b-h,d-e,c-i )
nn <- neighborhood( g, order=1, nodes=V(g) )
# > nn[[1]]
# + 6/8 vertices, named:
#   [1] a b c d e f
```

In other words, when calculating the neighborhood of node "a", `neighborhood` reports "a" first and then the nearest neighbors and so on.

I'd like to know if this order is not a coincidence and it's a true characteristic of the function that I can safely use in my program. I didn't find an answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a characteristic of the *current implementation* of the function, so right now you can rely on it. However, since it is not a part of the documentation, the authors of the package are free to change the behaviour in the next version without warning.